# Cannot append perf to file

Tags: linux, output, perf

I am using Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS and I have perf version 4.15.18. I trying to redirect and append the output of the following command of perf to a file but doesn't seem to work.

```
perf stat -a -e power/energy-cores/,power/energy-gpu/,power/energy-pkg/, power/energy-ram sleep 1 >> power.log
```

Answer (score 1):

`perf stat` writes to `stderr` by default, you're redirecting `stdout`.

Use the `--output` and `--append` options to specify where the results should be written.

```
perf stat -a --output power.log --append -e power/energy-cores/,power/energy-gpu/,power/energy-pkg/, power/energy-ram sleep 1
```